# Converting pandas DatetimeIndex to 'float days format' with Matplotlib.dates.datestr2num

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

Some Matplotlib methods need days in ['float days format'](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html). datestr2num is a converter function for this, but it falls over with the relevant pandas objects:

```
In [3]: type(df.index)
Out[3]: pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex
In [4]: type(df.index[0])
Out[4]: pandas.tslib.Timestamp
In [5]: mpl.dates.date2num(df.index)
Out [5]: ...
AttributeError: 'numpy.datetime64' object has no attribute 'toordinal'
```

This provides a usable list of times in 'float days format':

```
dates = [mpl.dates.date2num(t) for t in df.index]
```

But is there a better way?

Comment: What function do you want to use that needs this? And maybe you can use `mpl.dates.date2num(df.index.to_pydatetime())`?

Comment: Some of the mpl.finance plotting functions use 'float days format' although it seems a shame date2num can't natively deal with pandas DatetimeIndices. But your suggestion works perfectly thanks! (If you put it in an answer I'll tick it :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `to_pydatetime` method of the DatetimeIndex (this will convert it to an array of `datetime.datetime`'s, and `mpl.dates.date2num` will know how to handle those):

```
mpl.dates.date2num(df.index.to_pydatetime())
```

The reason that `date2num` does not natively handle a pandas DatetimeIndex, is because matplotlib does not yet support the numpy datetime64 dtype (which is how the data are stored in a DatetimeIndex).