# Matplotlib AutoDateLocator not working with DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a dataframe with a DatetimeIndex like so:

```
In [3]: index = pd.date_range('September 1 2014', 'September 1 2015', freq='M')
   ...: index
Out[3]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2014-09-30', '2014-10-31', '2014-11-30', '2014-12-31',
               '2015-01-31', '2015-02-28', '2015-03-31', '2015-04-30',
               '2015-05-31', '2015-06-30', '2015-07-31', '2015-08-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M'
```

Plotting without changing the x tick labels or explicit date formatting yields an x-axis from 0-12.

My figure contains 13 subplots in one column. I'm trying to set the x-axis on the last plot using AutoDateLocator() at the end of the code after all the subplots are plotted:

```
fig.axes[-1].xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.AutoDateLocator())
```

Which returns the following error:

```
ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1
```

I tried converting the dataframe index with dates2num  as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27993540/converting-pandas-datetimeindex-to-float-days-format-with-matplotlib-dates-dat) but it yielded the same result:

```
df.index = mdates.date2num(df.index.to_pydatetime())
```

I tried consulting the documentation but I couldn't dig up any other way to make matplotlib recognize the x-axis as dates.

Here is the complete code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import seaborn as sns

index = pd.date_range('September 1 2014', 'September 1 2015', freq='M')
data = np.random.random([12, 13])
df = DataFrame(data=data, index=index)
# Draw figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(19,20), dpi=72)
fig.suptitle('Chart', fontsize=40, color='#333333')

# Draw charts
for i in range(0, len(df)):

    ax = plt.subplot(len(df),1, i+1)

    # Set ticks and labels 
    ax.tick_params(direction='in', length=45, pad=60,colors='0.75')
    ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(size=0)
    ax.set_yticklabels([])
    ax.set_ylim([0, 2])
    plt.ylabel(df.columns[i], rotation=0, labelpad=60, fontsize=20, color='#404040')

   # Remove spines
   sns.despine(ax=ax, bottom=True)

   # Draw baseline, data, and threshold lines

   # Threshold
   ax.axhline(1.6, color='#a0db8e', linestyle='--', label='Threshold')

   # Draw baseline
   ax.axhline(1, color='0.55',label='Enterprise')

   # Plot data
   ax.plot(df.iloc[:, i], color='#14509f',label='Data')


# Subplot spacing
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=1)

# Hide tick labels and first/last tick lines
plt.setp([a.get_xticklabels() for a in fig.axes[:-1]], visible=False)
plt.setp([a.get_xticklines()[-2:] for a in fig.axes],visible=False)

# Date in x-axis
fig.axes[-1].xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.AutoDateLocator())
fig.axes[-1].xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y.%m.%d'))
```