# Polar chart of yearly data with matplolib

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series, polar-coordinates

I am trying to plot data for a whole year as a polar chart in matplotlib, and having trouble locating any examples of this. I managed to convert the dates from pandas according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27993540/converting-pandas-datetimeindex-to-float-days-format-with-matplotlib-dates-dat), but I can't wrap my head around (litterally) the y-axis, or theta.

This is how far I got:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import pandas as pd

times = pd.date_range("01/01/2016", "12/31/2016")
rand_nums = np.random.rand(len(times),1)
df = pd.DataFrame(index=times, data=rand_nums, columns=['A'])

ax = plt.subplot(projection='polar')
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax.set_theta_zero_location("N")
ax.plot(mdates.date2num(df.index.to_pydatetime()), df['A'])
plt.show()
```

which gives me this plot:

[image: this plot]

reducing the date range to understand what is going on
`times = pd.date_range("01/01/2016", "01/05/2016")` I get this plot:

[image: this plot]

I gather that the start of the series is between 90 and 135, but how can I 'remap' this so that my year date range starts and finishes at the north origin?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The polar plot's angle range ranges over a full circle in radiants, i.e. `[0, 2π]`.
 One would therefore need to normalize the date range to the full circle.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import pandas as pd

times = pd.date_range("01/01/2016", "12/31/2016")
rand_nums = np.random.rand(len(times),1)
df = pd.DataFrame(index=times, data=rand_nums, columns=['A'])

ax = plt.subplot(projection='polar')
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax.set_theta_zero_location("N")

t = mdates.date2num(df.index.to_pydatetime())
y = df['A']
tnorm = (t-t.min())/(t.max()-t.min())*2.*np.pi
ax.fill_between(tnorm,y ,0, alpha=0.4)
ax.plot(tnorm,y , linewidth=0.8)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I did before but it said I didn't have enough karma for it to count! I seem to have earned some now. Maybe I can use images in my next question.