# How to convert Pandas Timestamp to Matplotlib's float64 format?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

The code in below plots a Pandas Time Series with `milliseconds` unit.
However, Matplotlib stores this `milliseconds` timestamp as `float64` internally, so that I can reformat them to `hh:mm:ss` as shown in below. Does anyone know how to manually convert Pandas timestamp to Matplotlib's `float64` format? Thanks

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

x = np.arange(5000)
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['y'])
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.index, unit='ms')
df.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(df.index, df.y)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S'))
```

[image]

#### Matplotlib stores date in float64 format

```
print(ax.get_xlim())
>> (-2.892939814814815e-06, 6.075173611111111e-05)

print(type(ax.get_xlim()[0]))
>> numpy.float64

print(df.index[0])    # how to convert to -2.892939814814815e-06
>> 1970-01-01 00:00:00

print(df.index[-1])   # how to convert to 6.075173611111111e-05
>> 1970-01-01 00:00:04.999000
```

#### The `mdates.date2num()` doesn't work either

```
print(mdates.date2num(df.index[0]))
>> 0.0

print(mdates.date2num(df.index[-1]))
>> 5.785879629629629e-05
```

#### Final Update:

Sorry, I was wrong. The `mdates.date2num()` actually works! Initially I thought `ax.get_xlim()` was returning `(x[0], x[-1])`, but it actually returns something before x[0], and something after x[-1] so that the figure has some `padding` around the line. That's why it returns `(-2.892939814814815e-06, 6.075173611111111e-05)` instead of `(0.0, 5.785879629629629e-05)`. Now I finally get it. Thanks guys!!

Comment: This would help - https://stackoverflow.com/q/27993540/6075699

Comment: sorry, `to_pydatetime()` is not working either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `mdates.num2date()` is used to convert to the time managed by matplotlib.　Kindly refer to [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.date2num).

```
# print xlim in Matplotlib format
print(ax.get_xlim())
ts = mdates.num2date(ax.get_xlim()[0])
ts1 = mdates.num2date(ax.get_xlim()[1])
print(ts)
print(ts1)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I would like to convert the pandas date to matplotlib num, for example from `1970-01-01 00:00:00` to `-2.892939814814815e-06`

Comment: You can convert dates to numbers with `mdates.date2num(df.index[1])`.

Comment: I had already tried your suggestion, the answer is not the same.

Comment: The first value obtained by `get_xlim()` indicates the value of the origin on the graph, so the value is before 1970 and the actual value is 1969-12-31 23:59:59.750050+00:00. What do you say does not fit with what?

Comment: hi @r-beginners, I think you are right, `get_xlim()` does not return `x[0]` and `x[-1]`. I think I finally get it now. Thanks a lot ^_^